# How to connect Bluetooth mouse on Acer Aspire S3 Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I'm trying to start the Bluetooth Suite, but it won't start... Any ideas on how to get it running or how to pair the mouse to the computer?

Comment: Reinstalling Bluetooth Suite, updating driver (not needed) etc. Turns out the solution was pretty simple... I feel like a total dumba$$... ;) Fn + F3 to enable Bluetooth the manual said when I looked really closely... So it's all good now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was desperately simple; Bluetooth was not enabled by default (makes sense) and the hardware button to enable it was Fn+F3...

Comment: Please note that out of the box the S3 does not come with Bluetooth enabled, perhaps an understandable default, but somewhat difficult for users to enable.

Comment: I have enabled Bluetooth on my Acer S3 Ultrabook,but it does not detect any bluetooth devices when searched. I am able to find my Ultrabook on my Mobile, but my ultrabook does not detect other bluetooth devices. Would you let me know if there are any other things which I need to do to make the Bluetooth working?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there...